# What is the reason for not saving data in the database?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

My target is to store data from the `html form`. I tried different ways, bellow way is one of them. But data is not stored in the database. What is the problem? Is the way appropriate?

***views.py:***

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def employeeListView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        jsonData = JSONParser().parse(request)
        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(data=jsonData)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return JsonResponse(serializer.data, safe=False)
        else:
            return JsonResponse(serializer.errors, safe=False)

def InsertAndInfo(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = request.POST.get('name')
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        phone = request.POST.get('phone')
        data = {
            'name':name
        }
        headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

        read = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/employees/',json=data,headers=headers)

    return render(request, 'InsertAndInfo.html')
```

***models.py:***

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=30)
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)
```

***serializer.py:***

```
class EmployeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = "__all__"
```

***urls.py:***

```
path('', views.InsertAndInfo, name="InsertAndInfo"),
path('employees/', views.employeeListView, name="employeeListView")
```

***InsertAndInfo.html:***

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
</form>
```

Comment: This will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58269137/11697139
No need using JSONParser. Just `EmployeeSerializer(data=request.data)`

Comment: not working....

Answer (score 0):

### Try this...

```
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status

@api_view(['POST'])
def employeeListView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serializer = EmployeeSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: it's not working

Comment: remove max_length from email field Model

makemigrations and migrate then try again

Comment: name = request.POST.get('name')
email = request.POST.get('email')
phone = request.POST.get('phone')

Comment: model is oke,, mistakely I kept these two fields in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I changed `phone = models.IntegerField(null=True)` to `phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, null=True)`,, then It worked